# split a string by newline in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a json string for order.expeditionPlaces which is formatted like:

`"expeditionPlaces": "Place1, Place2, Place3"`

I am able to split the data but I can't get the string to go onto a new line as html tags are escaped within react

`{order.expeditionPlaces ? order.expeditionPlaces.split(",").join("<br>") : ""}`

should display:

`Place1`

`Place2`

How can I re-write this so the string splits onto new lines?

My current code is

```
if (this.state.possibleOrders && this.state.possibleOrders.length > 0) {
        this.state.possibleOrders.forEach((order, index) => {
            possibleOrders.push(<tr key={index}>
                <td>{order.orderId}</td>
                <td>{order.orderState}</td>
                <td>{order.expeditionPlaces ? order.expeditionPlaces.split(",").join("<br>") : ""}</td>
                <td>{order.sortingBufferPlaces}</td>
            </tr>);
        });
    }
```

Comment: What does it display at the moment?

Comment: BTW, is it throwing any errors in console? I am sure your code is not working at all.

Comment: Use map and generate a div for each item: http://www.hackingwithreact.com/read/1/13/rendering-an-array-of-data-with-map-and-jsx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your case JSX does not interpret `"<br />"` as a `HTML tag`, but as a `string`, so

```
<td>
{
  order.expeditionPlaces 
    ? order.expeditionPlaces.split(",").join("<br>") 
    : ""
}
</td>
```

should be

```
<td>
{
  order.expeditionPlaces 
    ? order.expeditionPlaces.split(",").map(place => <p> {place} </p>) 
    : ""
}
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your actual code returns a string when you need a react component :)

This code should work (not tested, might need some ajustments)

```
if (this.state.possibleOrders && this.state.possibleOrders.length > 0) {
    this.state.possibleOrders.forEach((order, index) => {
        possibleOrders.push(<tr key={index}>
            <td>{order.orderId}</td>
            <td>{order.orderState}</td>
            <td>
                {(order.expeditionPlaces || []).split(",").map(function(place, i) {
                    return <p key={i}>place</p>
                })}
            </td>
            <td>{order.sortingBufferPlaces}</td>
        </tr>);
    });
}
```

-EDIT
replace

```
<p>
```

with whatever needed

```
<div key={i}>place<br/></div>
```

will work too